# Software Recommendation for Theorem Suggestions

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question, math-software, formal-proofs

So I am not sure if this software already exists or perhaps this is something that humanity has to embark on to finally have as a product. A bit about myself, I am student training in a sub-area of Mathematical Logic.

My question is as follows, I wished to know if there is a software which can give us past theorems as suggestions once I write out my hunch for the problem statement I formalised after doing my literature survey? I feel this would be just like the similar questions suggestions menu stackexchange has in it's interface.

If the answer to the above is a `no' or it's a software in progress, then, I would wish to know the thoughts of the community on how such a software could be formed.

Two challenges for such a tool that at least I can spot immediately are:

1. First the **Database** of theorems on which this software will do a query or similarity analysis, perhaps that in itself is a task that at least manually would be really challenging. Perhaps a faster way to achieve this would be to train some machine learning algorithm to convert the Theorem or Proposition speak into a more rigorous formal language version amenable for the Search Query version. And, then crawl on the mathematical literature accessible.
2. The definition of the notion of **similarity** between two theorems. As a logician, my take here would be, what we wish to always search for are theorem "forms", keeping the domains of the objects/variables separate. The domains of the object would have certain properties that will make each proofs slightly different, which is what the user querying such a question will have to figure out.

An illustration of what I mean above is : "$\exists x : x^2 = -1$", this is a theorem "form" in my eyes, this particular statement would have different proofs about it's validity in different domains ($\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$) of interpretation.

If there are further aspects that make this task an impossible or an incredibly difficult one do let me know.

Comment: A keyword that might point you to existing research in this direction is "mathematical knowledge management".

Comment: Ah, I see, I shall look into it and get back to you or this question with a self answer.